# manipulating firebase served statics on the fly

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm serving my web-app with **firebase hosting**. A few aspects of my app are configureable based on user context (e.g. localization), and configuration is done in app's `index.html`.

Typically, I'd use a template engine on my own backend (e.g. velocity) to solve this problem, but there isn't seem to be an out-of-the-box solution for that.

- Is there a workaround or a hack'ish way to do so with firebase?
- Is there a way to execute code which will modify my statics?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Firebase Hosting for detecting the browser locale and sending a locale-specific response. But you can easily accomplish this from the client-side. Some links to get you started:

- [Load Locale File Dynamically using Requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621586/load-locale-file-dynamically-using-requirejs)
- [in Angular How to Dynamically Load javascript file depending of user language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377483/in-angular-how-to-dynamically-load-javascript-file-depending-of-user-language)
- [Serving a language file depending on language preference settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308372/serving-a-language-file-depending-on-language-preference-settings)
- [How to select the file depending on the browser language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134982/how-to-select-the-file-depending-on-the-browser-language)
- the [Google query that I got these from](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=load+javascript+based+on+user+locale)

### Update

Firebase Hosting has not built-in server-side templating mechanism, not any other way to run your code on Firebase's servers.

See:

- [Simple PHP contact form with Firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523819/simple-php-contact-form-with-firebase-hosting)

Comment: thanks @frank-van-puffelen, it seems my question was not well-written, so I've updated it. Detection of user locale is not my concern, but rather the ability to pre-configure my entire served app (via `index.html`), where locale is just one example. i was actually looking for a velocity-like solution on firebase side.

Comment: Added a link about that to my answer. I'll mark your question as a duplicate of that question.